# Cannot load SavedModel

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm training some models using tf.keras and want to save the trained model. There are two recommended ways of doing this, tf `SavedModel` and keras `.h5` file. However things get really confusing with `SavedModel`.

Here are some short scripts to reproduce the issue:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def my_network():
    backbone_model = tf.keras.applications.InceptionResNetV2(
        include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3), weights="imagenet", pooling="avg"
    )

    inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3), name="images")
    backbone_features = backbone_model(inputs)
    pre_embeddings = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
        512,
        activation=None,
        name="pre_embeddings",
        kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(),
    )(backbone_features)

    embeddings = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(
        lambda x: tf.math.l2_normalize(x, 1, 1e-10), name="embeddings"
    )(pre_embeddings)

    probs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
        1000,
        activation="softmax",
        name="predictions",
        kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(),
        bias_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(),
    )(pre_embeddings)

    return tf.keras.Model(inputs, [embeddings, probs], name="my_network")


img_arr = np.random.rand(1, 224, 224, 3)

resnet_model = my_network()
emb_1, _ = resnet_model.predict(img_arr)
resnet_model.save("./resnet_model.h5")

new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('./resnet_model.h5')
emb_2, _ = new_model.predict(img_arr)

np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(emb_1, emb_2)
```

The above script will work without errors. However it fails when I tried to save in the `SavedModel` format (by removing `.h5` from model path). The model saved successfully but throws an error when loading and the error message is:

```
NotImplementedError: When subclassing the `Model` class, you should implement a `call` method.
```

I am confused because I did not use any subclassed model. As shown in the script, my network is built with functional API only.

Comment: what is your tf version?

Comment: I'm using TF2.1, installed from latest pip package